# bluebird.js vs bluebird.core.js what is the difference?

Tags: bluebird

What is the difference between bluebird.js and bluebird.core.js?

When should I use bluebird.core.js instead of bluebird.js?

I haven't been able to find anything in the [bluebird site](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bluebird has partial builds that don't include features of the library and in return result in a lower file size. It's smaller than a small image anyway - but it's still worth saving those few bytes for production sites.

So `bluebird.core.js` includes only the very minimal parts of the library. `bluebird.js` includes the full library.

At the moment, the build is kind of quirky (the library itself is super stable though) and we don't really generate `.core.js` files automatically. We need to fix that.

I'll edit that into the docs so it's clearer. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Would it be possible to be a little more clear as to what "minimal parts" mean? Does the core build support e.g. the full native Promise API?

Comment: Yes, it does include that - the header of the file actually contains a list of supported features

Answer (score 0):

I'm really late to the party but just to throw my two cents into the discussion:

As you can see in the sourcecode of [bluebird.core.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.5.2/bluebird.core.js)

> Features disabled:
>
> race, call_get, generators, map, nodeify,
>
> promisify, props, reduce, settle, some,
>
> using, timers, filter, any, each

I use `map`, `mapSeries`, `each` and `reduce` thoroughly, so I guess core build isn't for me.